# Irregularities in Elasticsearh Aggregarions

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elastic-stack

I am using elasticsearch for creating some aggregation reports. Here is my aggregation query

```
{
  "size":10,
  "_source":["country_iso", "username"],
   "aggs":{
    "Granulated Reports":{
      "date_histogram" :{
        "field":"aggr_time",
        "interval" : "month"
      },
      "aggs":{
        "calls":{
          "sum":{"field":"bill_duration"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get a doc_count of 27000 but if I remove the aggregation calls and make it

```
{
  "size":10,
  "_source":["country_iso", "username"],
  "aggs":{
    "Granulated Reports":{
      "date_histogram" :{
        "field":"aggr_time",
        "interval" : "month"
      },
      "aggs":{

      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting a doc_count of 44000. My understanding is that the doc_count should differ only if i change a query or a filter. Adding or deleting aggregations should not have any effect on the number of documents it is scanning. The Doc_count goes down if I add another aggregation. I am not able to understand this behavior as this is giving different answers based on the number of aggregations.

Comment: What ES version and the `doc_count` of which aggregation?

Comment: es version 1.5.2 and the doc_count in general -> 
  "aggregations" : {
    "Granulated Reports" : {
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key_as_string" : "2015-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "key" : 1448928000000,
        **"doc_count"** : 115701,
        "calls" : {
          "value" : 6.7635164E7
        }
      } ]
    }